# JsXml object doesn't support the operation getNodeType, and this is causing the unsupported operation exception

Tags: xpath, karate, gherkin

I have a Java class where below method exists:
public String replace(Document xmlDocument, Map<String, String> inputMap)

Note - I am reading a soap xml and then calling replace method to eliminate the optional components from the structure.

I want to call the above replace method in karate framework but getting below exception:
Karate - * def payload = xpathProcessor.replace(testDocument, inputMap)
There's an issue with trying to access properties or methods (getNodeType) of a JavaScript object (JsXml) from Java. Pleas help here.

```
* def payload = xpathProcessor.replace(testDocument, inputMap)
js failed:
>>>>
01: xpathProcessor.replace(testDocument, inputMap)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Unsupported operation identifier 'getNodeType' and  object '{soap:Envelope={_={soap:Header={context={_={authToken=#{required}, session={_=#{optional}, @={id=#{optional}, proxy=#{optional}, seq=#{op...'(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsXml). Identifier is not executable or instantiable.
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.unsupported(PolyglotEngineException.java:137)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotInteropErrors.invokeUnsupported(PolyglotInteropErrors.java:193)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotObjectProxyHandler$ProxyInvokeNode.invokeOrExecute(PolyglotObjectProxyHandler.java:250)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotObjectProxyHandler$ProxyInvokeNode.doCachedMethod(PolyglotObjectProxyHandler.java:205)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotObjectProxyHandlerFactory$ProxyInvokeNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PolyglotObjectProxyHandlerFactory.java:124)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotObjectProxyHandlerFactory$ProxyInvokeNodeGen.execute(PolyglotObjectProxyHandlerFactory.java:65)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotObjectProxyHandler$ObjectProxyNode.executeImpl(PolyglotObjectProxyHandler.java:147)
```

Tried using google Gson implementation as an alternative but still failing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Karate does not support passing XML `Document` types in [Java interop](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java).

If you need to return XML back from Java to Karate, I suggest converting it to a String. Once in Karate you can do `karate.fromString()` to convert it to XML or use the [type-conversion](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion) hints.

Comment: Getting explanation on chatgpt: The error you are encountering is due to the fact that the xmlDocument you are passing seems to be of the type com.intuit.karate.graal.JsXml which is not compatible with the Document type expected by the replace method in your XpathProcessorImpl class.
The JsXml type is a JavaScript object created by Karate to represent XML content in a script. However, your Java class XpathProcessorImpl is designed to work with Java’s native Document type.  Can you help on this?